What could cause potential runtime issue when calling a Transactional method from another non-Transactional method of same class?
this is a conceptually question for understanding Transactions in Spring.
What potential runtime issue this code can cause? I know when we will try to run it, the transactional context will be missing but fetchCourses() method will still work.
Can there be a scenario where this code will cause runtime issue due to calling Transactional method from same class?
@Component
public class Student {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepo;

    public boolean isEnrolled(String studentId, Course course) {
        return fetchCourses(studentId).contains(course);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Course> fetchCourses(String studentId) {
        return studentRepo.findByStudentId(studentId).getPermissions();
    }
}

I tried it using Mongodb and it was working. So I couldn't produce potential runtime issue with it.

First you ask why it won't run and say it should work, but then you say you tried it and it was working. So what is your actual question? It's a bad idea anyway, since as you say, it will not actually be transactional, but may trick future maintenance developers into thinking that it is transactional.

@DavidConrad Hi, sorry it was very ambiguous earlier. I have tried to clarify it now.

There is nothing wrong with this code. Calling a transactional method from the same class is a valid case. Why do you thing it can cause a runtime issue?

BTW if the StudentRepository is an JPA repository then using @Transactional is obsolet. Transactions will be handled already in SimpleJpaRepository. Check the code for details: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java

@Mar-Z This is just an interview question code from a company that is very fond of transactions. Not really code from codebase.

@Mar-Z Code has design issue. It is failing separation of concern principle. Data is being fetched and business logic being applied in same class. They told me separating this code will also help with issue that we might face due to Transactional. I don't know what that issue is.

@Transactional(readOnly = true)

Will be ignored (except AspectJ, visit the comments)!

... unless the OP uses native AspectJ mode. In that case, it will not be ignored and indeed be transactional.

@kriegaex I was thinking same. Can we have potential runtime issue in that case? Maybe related to LazyLoadingExcpation?

I choose not to answer your hypothetical question. I recommend to try for yourself and ask a new question, accompanied by a complete, minimal reproducer in case of a new problem.
